# How an I retrofit smart bulbs in a LED fixture?

Tags: lighting, led

I have a lot of these lights in my house (kitchen, bathrooms, bedrooms)

They look like LEDs but it also looks like the only way to change them is by soldering.  is this true?

I really want to upgrade them to smart lights (Zigbee or Alexa integrated).  But I haven't found any options (maybe just using bad keywords for search).  Does anyone know of a smart light option that supports this [pictured] configuration?

[image]

Comment: Imagine those solder connections just for the light itself.  Should be wire disconnects(screws,wire nuts) in grey housing or behind plate.  Disconnect power first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 1 - Replace Fixtures

Loosen the two screws in the slots. Rotate the fixture so that the screws end up in the larger holes at the ends of the slots. Pull the fixture down. You should find wires from the fixture connected to either individual wires or a cable coming from the electric supply. There may be multiple cables/wire sets - supply, switch, feed to other fixtures. **Take pictures before disconnecting anything**. Generally speaking, there will be 3 connections (hot, neutral, ground) to remove/replace in order to replace the fixture.

Advantages: Individual fixture control, multi-color control (with some LEDs).

#### Option 2 - Replace Switches

Similar to above (easier, because you don't need to climb up to the ceiling), but at the switch instead of the fixture.

Advantages: 1 switch might control several fixtures, no need to figure out the right size for each fixture (both physically and amount of light), safer as switch can always manually override "smart" controls.

Comment: didnt even think to replace switches!

Comment: If all you need is remote control (and not truly special fixtures), switches are a **lot** easier. Plus if the smarts fail, you can always put in a standard switch as a very inexpensive temporary fix.

Comment: Smart switches are $50+ each, but can control an (almost) unlimited number of fixtures. Smart fixtures can are likely also $50+ each. In order to control 2 fixtures in one room, you have to replace both. Not only is it _easier_ to replace one switch, it's _far_ more _cost effective_.

Comment: Replacing the switches will work IF and here's the big IF....the switches were either not connected via switch leg OR if wired via a switch leg, that /3 + ground was run as is required in recent code.   Smart switches usually require a neutral to operate and if that's not available, they won't work.

Comment: I like to be clear and maybe I wasn't by using industry slang:  A switch leg is when power goes first to the fixture and then a cable goes to the switch. In older wiring the problem with installing smart switches is they usually require a neutral for the tiny bit of power they use and a neutral isn't available. Older versions of the code allowed "bootlegging" the ground as a neutral for devices like this, but I don't think that's allowed anymore.  More modern "switch legs" are required to have 3 conductors and a ground, to support smart devices.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Good point. But the good news is that (a) if OP has these fixtures all over the house, it is likely they are original and not retrofit, in which case the house is relatively new and should have neutral @ switches; (b) there are **some** switches available that *legally* use ground instead of neutral (but you have to be sure you get the right ones and install them properly); (c) some smart switches (especially "remote" 3-ways) are battery powered. So there are a lot of possibilities and "old switch legs" is not always as bad as it seems (except when it is...)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Could be a modern house, but maybe not, we just don't know.   I recently supervised an upgrade of an old parsonage on our church property, 1930 era house and we replaced all the light fixtures with LED like the one the OP posted. And depending upon what NEC code is adopted in the OP's jurisdiction bootlegging a neutral onto a ground may or may not be allowed.  I'm gunna get snipped for this, but frankly, it's a pretty safe thing to do, even if not code legal in their area.

Answer (score 1):

The "way to change them" is to replace the whole fixture.

If you want a "smart" fixture replace them with a "smart" fixture or a "dumb" fixture with "smart" bulbs in "dumb" sockets.

Comment: However, the "dumb" sockets will probably be a Building Code violation.  Generally, installation of Edison sockets in newer homes is not permitted because of energy/grid load regulations.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Are you saying Edison (screw) sockets are not permitted in new build? Do you have a link/reference?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Is that really "generally"? I thought it was just a California thing. Or has that "virus" spread to the rest of the country?

Comment: I'd like to hear about this as well.  It doesn't appear to have made it to Canada yet.  It wouldn't hurt to add the option of smart switches to this answer since they're probably the best cost effect although it reduces control options.